# HBase : How to calculate size of the data particular Columnfamily

Tags: java, hadoop, hbase, size, storage

In HBase, like RowCounter Mapreduce job is there any way to calculate size of the data stored in particular column family between startRow and StopRow.

For calculating the whole table, we can use

> hdfs dfs -du -h  /hbase/data/default/

I have checked this one.

http://prafull-blog.blogspot.com/2012/06/how-to-calculate-record-size-of-hbase.html

I need only the Variable part of the KeyValue to calculate size in the Mapreduce format.

In periodcally I need to calculate size of the data stored in the range of the row key.

Please help

Comment: do you need on-disk size or size of actual data which you wrote(without overhead of HBase storage layer)?

Comment: @Lagrang on-disk size. I think the actual size data can't be calculated as we have enabled compression policy for all tables in our deployment.

Comment: yes, compression and other HBase related overhead will make your task very hard to do.

Comment: @Lagrang Is there any way available to calculate on-disk size particular column family between startRow and StopRow.